# What are loops used for

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, soft-question

A set $X$ with a binary operation $*$ that satisfy all the conditions required to be a group except associativity is called a $loop$.

Before starting studying this subject (since the art is long and life is short) I'm wondering what are they used for? Is there any real reason to study loops or all the nice results appears only with the group structure? Any good reference will be upvoted.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, why are you considering studying them in the first place?

Comment: One of the first thing I do to gain some insight in such situation is browsing an encyclopedia (Of course asking a question here is also a good idea). I know nothing about loops and what makes you interested in, but [this](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Loop) tells me it is a concept used in the theory of [quasi-groups](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quasi-group) and a keyword [Moufang loop](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Moufang_loop). Ah, now you might have another two questions what are these used for?

Comment: @orat Quasi-group is just a loop without identity.:) Now Moufang loops are more interesting they are sort of going closer to a group. You get a type of limited associativity.:)

Comment: studying Lie algebras I became acquinted on how useful non associative algebras are, but I think we cannot say lie brackets are loops since they don't have identity

Comment: Non-associative algebras in general are not actually that much studied. One will usually have some additional requirement to replace it (such as the Jacobi identity for Lie algebras or the multiplicative norm for composition algebras).